# a token of one's personality or person

Tags: meaning-in-context

> **gauntlet (n.1)**
>
> "glove," early 15c., *gantelet*, from Old French gantelet (13c.) "gauntlet worn by a knight in armor," also ***a token of one's personality or person***, and in medieval custom symbolizing a challenge, as in *tendre son gantelet* "throw down the gauntlet" (a sense found in English by 1540s).

---

[Source](https://www.etymonline.com/word/gauntlet#etymonline_v_1320)

I'd like to know if "***a token of one's personality or person***" means "a token of one's personality or a token of person".

Comment: It's in the dictionary. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A token of my person" means something you can have to stand in for me when we can't be together.

It's similar to a *reminder of me* or a *memento of me*, but where those two have the feeling of maintaining some memory of the past, a *token of someone's person* is supposed to stand in for them actually being with you at that moment.

A modern version of it is like if your sweetheart moves far away for university, and you give them a cute stuffed animal and tell them to pretend it's you, like you're still with them. Same idea, but we don't use that language anymore.

Comment: May I ask a question about your reply? I'd also like to know if the "to" in "something you can have to stand in for me" can be substituted with "in order to".

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss No, we only use "in order to" to give the purpose of verbs, not nouns, and "token" is a noun. A neater way of phrasing that sentence would be, "*...means something to stand in for me...*" without "you can have".

Answer (score 1):

*A token of person* makes no sense. It must be *a token of my personality or a token of my person*. As to what this might actually mean, see my answer to your other question.